# How the Perl advanced sort is sorting the values by using the $a and $b values in the sort function

Tags: perl, sorting

```
@array=sort{$a <=> $b} @input;
@input = qw \  3 4 5 1 6 3 9 \;
```

so here how the perl internally sort the values.

so by which way the values are sorted in the perl advanced sorting and which sort method it is used to sort the values and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function in Perl sort the values according to [Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

For example:

```
my @num = (21, 3, 14, 5);
my @sorted = sort @num;
print join(',', @sorted), "\n";
```

This will give the output:

```
14,21,3,5
```

So here 14 and 21 is before that 3, but you were expecting 3 first. So here when it was comparing 21 and 3, it compares them as string. Means it was comparing the first character of both string i.e. `2` and `3`, and 2 comes before that 3 in Ascii table, so it put 21 before 3.

By default Perl doesn't understand that you want to sort them as numbers.

So to solve this we use a comparison operator `<=>` which compare this array elements as numbers.

To sort them in ascending and descending order we use `$a` and `$b`. When you write a code block `{$a <=> $b}`, it tells to Perl that for each pair of elements in the input, passes them to as `$a` and `$b`, and it compare and return:

- `-1` if `$a` is less than `$b`
- `1` if `$a` is greater than `$b`
- `0` if `$a` equals `$b`

Comment: but how it is internally sort the values and which method of sorting it takes for sort the values in perl advacned sort.

Answer (score 3):

[`perldoc sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html):

> Perl 5.6 and earlier used a quicksort algorithm to implement sort. That algorithm was not stable and could go quadratic. (A stable sort preserves the input order of elements that compare equal. Although quicksort's run time is O(NlogN) when averaged over all arrays of length N, the time can be O(N**2), quadratic behavior, for some inputs.) In 5.7, the quicksort implementation was replaced with a stable mergesort algorithm whose worst-case behavior is O(NlogN).

Comment: what is the sorting algorithm is used for the perl advanced sort operator now.For the latest version what type of sorting algorithm it is using

Comment: @dhanagovidarajan According to the comments in the [source](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/cc93400aa5a8d556c56c28a8de644bd178d050d4/pp_sort.c#L71), it uses a binary merge sort. There's a description of the algorithm in the comments [here](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/cc93400aa5a8d556c56c28a8de644bd178d050d4/pp_sort.c#L139).